# Adding global filters outside OnModelCreating

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a multi tenant app where the user after login succesfully is redirected to a page where he can select the enterprise he wants to work with.

I need to add a lot of global filters that depend on the enterprise Id. But it seems OnModelCreating is called when the dbcontext is created. And the dbcontext is created when the user wants to login, but, at this time I don't yet know the enterprise he wants to work with because he haven't yet selected it. So, I can't add the filters.

I would like to add these filters when the enterprise id is selected. Is it possible? Because all examples I have seen add them in OnModelCreating and haven't found any reference on doing it in other places.

This is an example of the OnModelCreating method:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    //Last in wins so first set base model features
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    HttpContext httpContext = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;


    if (httpContext.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("X-TENANT-ID") == true)
    {
        string tenant = httpContext.Request.Headers["X-TENANT-ID"];
        int enterpriseId = int.Parse(tenant);

        //Define global filters for all entities
        modelBuilder.Entity<Enterprise>().HasQueryFilter(p => !p.IsDeleted);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Vehicle>().HasQueryFilter(o => o.EnterpriseId == enterpriseId && !o.IsDeleted);
        modelBuilder.Entity<BillingInfo>().HasQueryFilter( o => o.EnterpriseId == enterpriseId && !o.IsDeleted);
        modelBuilder.Entity<DriverAppUser>().HasQueryFilter( o => o.EnterpriseId == enterpriseId && !o.IsDeleted);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Agency>().HasQueryFilter( o => o.EnterpriseId == enterpriseId && !o.IsDeleted);
        modelBuilder.Entity<InsuranceCarrier>().HasQueryFilter( o => o.EnterpriseId == enterpriseId && !o.IsDeleted);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Particular>().HasQueryFilter( o => o.EnterpriseId == enterpriseId && !o.IsDeleted);
    }
}
```

How would you do this?

Comment: We recently did this in our application with an almost identical problem and scenario where the user can choose his tenant. If your Context is set to transient or scoped when the user loads the 2nd page (the one requiring the filter) a new context should get created which will run through this OnModelCreating again.
Also, since your X-TENANT-ID is in the Http headers make sure you have validation that the user doesn't maliciously send a tenant ID they don't actually have access to.

Comment: @JeffreyParks I add the DbContext using the extension method services.AddDbContext and can assure you that OnModelCreating is just called first time a request is made to the WebApi. I have been checking the sources and this extension method registers the service as scoped. So, How is it that it works for you? :/. Transient is not an option.

Comment: I think I need a bit more sleep. You stated to create a new dbContext. Would you mind adding some code to see how do you create this new dbcontext and how do you added to the dependency inyection system? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: When a request comes to the server it creates new instances of the Controller/Service/DbContext (dunno exactly what hierarchy you have but it's the same concept). This means that every HTTP request gets a new DbContext, which means your code as is should work if everything is set to either Transient and/or Scoped. If I get more time later I can post a complete example as an answer.

Comment: Just to add a bit of information. Entity framework has a caching system. The documentation clearly states that overcoming it could lead to performance problems. I am starting to think about not using global filters and have some helper methods to add common filters like tenant and softdelete. Anyway I will really appreciate how you did built your solucion. Thanks!

Comment: Entity Framework's caching mechanism works within a DbContext, so if the DbContext is set to scoped it is only cached for that scope (IE that Http Request). When a new HTTP request is made, a new DbContext is created and then injected.

Comment: After having a looong sleep I see now what you mean :). Thanks for the patience. Please, when you have some time, answer with that example. It will be really helpfull.

Comment: Ok, I finally managed to do this but the problems still persists. I have 2 DbContext, one that handles all the login/selection of the tenant and another that is used to handle all operations a user can do per tenant. Then I use the one I need through DI and OnModelCreating. The problem is that this will called only for the first user that selects an enterprise to work with. The ones that come later will use the Model setup from this first user. Most important, they will use the global filters based on this tenant user. Did you solve this problem too? Perhaps using a custom Model catcher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got it. I'm using 2 DbContexts as Jeffrey Parks suggested and a IModelCacheKeyFactory class to generate a different key per tenant.

The DBContext that needs to run OnModelCreating depending on the tenant needs to be definned as:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{ 
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public int EnterpriseId { get; protected set;  } = -1;

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) : base(options)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        EnterpriseId = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetCurrentEnterpriseIdNotNull();
    }

    ...

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //Last in wins so first set base model features
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        HttpContext httpContext = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;

        int enterpriseId = httpContext.GetCurrentEnterpriseIdNotNull();                

        //Define global filters for all entities
        modelBuilder.Entity<Vehicle>().HasQueryFilter(o => o.EnterpriseId == EnterpriseId && !o.IsDeleted);
        ...
     }
}
```

Notice how I'm using the method GetCurrentEnterpriseIdNotNull to get the TenantId. This is a HTTPContext extension method that gets a claim from HttpContext.User that was previously inserted and verfied by a middleware. You can replace it with your code to get the tenant. It can be a service, etc.

The Key generator for caching the models is pretty simple:

```
public class TenantModelCacheKeyFactory : IModelCacheKeyFactory
{
    public object Create(DbContext context) =>

        context is ApplicationDbContext dynamicContext
            ? (context.GetType(), dynamicContext.EnterpriseId)
            : (object)context.GetType();

}
```

Notice how it extracts the tenantId from the created DbContext (That is created for every HTTP request).

After this, if you run a request with a correct tenant id a new Model cache will be created after calling OnModelCreating for this tenant and everything will run smooth. If another user logins for the same tenant, no new model will be created and the cached one will be served (Remember that the DbContext is always created per request because it was added as a scoped service). If another user logins with a differnt tenantId, again, the OnModelCreating will be called and another Model Cache will be created too and served.